# Get non-public facebookinformation from visitors at any time

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

*This might be an easy question, but I'd like your help with this. I couldn't find a solution on stackoverflow neither with google, probably cause I don't know what to search.*

---

I'm using the facebook API for some purposes. Users who are visiting the page, need to login with facebook and give standard access to there profile. The only thing I store at the moment is there facebookid.

The issue:
On this page I need the amount of friends (just the countnumber) from the last users who visited the page. (for some purposes) To bad the friends are not publicly accessible.

What's the best solution to retrieve this?

1. Storing the access token (is this still possible in a way?) and get friends with graph.facebook.com/*-id-*/friends?access_token=...
2. Is there another way to get count of friends?

I'd rather not save the amount of friends in the db, cause this is not accurate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect offline_access extended permission. And then to access other friend data, please cllect the friend_* extended permissions listed in the following SO url

[Facebook Graph API - get friends info](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5516627/facebook-graph-api-get-friends-info/7795013#7795013)

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you! The offline_access is probably what I was looking for! I'll give it a try.